# php array, only last item in array is correct

Tags: php, arrays

Below is the code that should make the problem clear. Code that is irrelevant to the problem has been left out, e.g. fetching the contents of a url, printing the contents to a new file.

Can anyone explain why variables are jumbled except for the last item?

```
<?php


$f = fopen("cucina2.txt", "r");

// Read line by line until end of file
    while (!feof($f)) { 

// Make an array using newline as delimiter
    $arrM = explode("\n",fgets($f));


//Add the word to the url address
    $url = 'hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/' . $arrM[0] . '/';

//Create a text file with the word
    $glossary = $arrM[0];
    $glossary .= '.txt';


//Check the functions
    echo "arrM is: ";
    echo $arrM[0];
    echo "\n";
    echo "glossary is: ";
    echo $glossary;
    echo "\n";
    echo "url is: ";
    echo $url;
    echo "\n";
    }

?>
```

---

cucina.txt:

```
batticarne
battuto
bavarese
bavetta
```

---

results:

```
arrM is: batticarne
.txtsary is: batticarne
/rl is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/batticarne
arrM is: battuto
.txtsary is: battuto
/rl is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/battuto
arrM is: bavarese
.txtsary is: bavarese
/rl is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/bavarese
arrM is: bavetta
glossary is: bavetta.txt
url is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/bavetta/
```

Comment: You got me, but just FYI, you have a typo here `'hhttp://www.some.com/` there are 2 `h`'s

Comment: Not sure why, maybe your lines are null-terminated, and then trim it will solve the problem, as pointed u_mulder. However, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your data file (cucina.txt) contains Windows-style line breaks ("`\r\n`"). When you split the input lines at `\n`, you are left with a trailing carriage return `\r` at the end of each slice.

Try this instead:

```
$arrM = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/',fgets($f));
```

Also, be aware that `while (!feof($f))` is generally wrong. You should check for an EOF when you are actually reading from the file, not at the top of your loop. That way you will avoid processing empty lines.

```
while (!feof($f)) { 
    $s = fgets($f);
    if (!$s) break;
    $arrM = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/',$s);
      :
      :
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your file. Made my own word list however.

I put just a list of stuff around me in into a text file:

`style
charity
new
samsung
asus
sharpie
tape`

It prints fine. Returns

`arrM is: style
glossary is: style.txt
url is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/style/
arrM is: charity
glossary is: charity.txt
url is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/charity/
arrM is: new
glossary is: new.txt
url is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/new/
arrM is: samsung
glossary is: samsung.txt
url is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/samsung/
arrM is: asus
glossary is: asus.txt
url is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/asus/
arrM is: sharpie
glossary is: sharpie.txt
url is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/sharpie/
arrM is: tape
glossary is: tape.txt
url is: hhttp://www.some.com/vocab/tape/`

Your issue could be coming from using explode. If the file your reading from is already words or series of words denoted from one another by line returns you don't need to explode the string. Just read the file line by line until you reach the end.

```
<?php

       //create variable to iterate though the array until it is out of values.
   $itter = 0;

   $f = fopen("WordsList.txt", "r");

     // Read line by line until end of file
while (!feof($f)) { 

//read the text file line by line.
$line=fgets($f);

    //Removed any whitespace left at the end of the line or whitespace generated from returning.
    //Trim can be used to trim any character from a string though.
$line=trim($line);

    //Add the line to the array.
$arrM[]=$line;


    //Add the word to the url address
$url = 'http://www.some.com/vocab/' . $arrM[$itter] . '/';

   //Create a text file with the word
$glossary = $arrM[$itter];
$glossary .= '.txt';


   //Check the functions
echo "arrM is: ";
echo $arrM[$itter];
echo "<br />";
echo "glossary is: ";
echo $glossary;
echo "<br />";
echo "url is: ";
echo $url;
echo "<br />";

  $itter++;
}
  //After you read from a file always a food idea to close it/dump it from memory.
fclose($f);
?>
```

Try that block of code. It uses trim to `fgets` to read line by line. Then trims any white space from the end of the line. Every time a line is pulled out by fgets it trims and sets that line equal to the variable `$line`. Then as each line is read and stripped it takes that line and adds it to your array.

The variable `$itter` then echos back the array starting at zero until it reaches the end of the number of lines found in the file/array generated from the file.

Comment: Problem was line endings. Changing from CR LF to LF solved the problem. Thanks for a very insightful observation.